# nginx - 403 forbidden for the 2nd domain

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, iredmail

I know this was discussed many many times but no other topic fixed my problem. I am running nginx on ubuntu 18.04 and also I got the iRedMail installed on this machine. The iRedMail admin page and roundcube works brilliant but I am trying to create a 2nd virtual host to host a 2nd website but I am getting the 403 Forbidden error when launching the browser and pointing to the 2nd domain.

The xxx.xxx.com is working perfect.
The xxx.com goes into 403 Forbidden page.

I'm a noob so please don't get mad if it's a stupid mistake.

00-default-ssl.conf of nginx

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name xxx.xxx.com;

  root /var/www/html;
  index index.php index.html;

  include /etc/nginx/templates/misc.tmpl;
  include /etc/nginx/templates/ssl.tmpl;
  include /etc/nginx/templates/iredadmin.tmpl;
  include /etc/nginx/templates/roundcube.tmpl;
  include /etc/nginx/templates/sogo.tmpl;
  include /etc/nginx/templates/netdata.tmpl;
  include /etc/nginx/templates/php-catchall.tmpl;
  include /etc/nginx/templates/stub_status.tmpl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.xxx.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.xxx.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name xxx.com;

  root /var/www/site;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Nginx's error log:

```
[error] 17970#17970: *1 directory index of "/var/www/site/" is forbidden, client: 80.31.xx.xxx, server: xxx.com, request: "GET /site/ HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx.com"
```

Comment: You haven't specified an index in the second block and have you set permissions properly for ``/var/www/site``?

Comment: I did an chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/site and chmod -R 755 /var/www/site and also I tried to add an index index.php; in the 00-default-ssl.conf for the 2nd virtual host. Still didn't worked

Comment: Do you have an index file in /var/www/site ?

Comment: I got the index.php from the CMS I uploaded.